# Transitive closure in a graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a directed graph 
x->y
y->z

i would like to add to this grpah transitive closure 
x->z

What should i change in my algorithen cause now i am creating every possible combination between x,y and z in both directions.

My code is below.

```
def transitive_closure(G):
    TC = nx.DiGraph()
    TC.add_nodes_from(G.nodes())
    TC.add_edges_from(G.edges())
    for v in G:
        TC.add_edges_from((v, u) for u in nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(G, source=v)
                      if v != u)
    return TC
```

Comment: Is G a digraph?  This certainly looks like it ought to work.  Have you tried printing out all the edges `(v,u)` in the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can try an iterative solution. First, instead of creating a new graph with all the nodes and edges of the last one, just copy it:

```
TC = G.copy()
```

Then iterate over the nodes and add all the neighbours of neighbours to be neighbours of `x`:

```
for x in G:
    # Extract all neighbours of neighbours of x (from G)
    all_nh = []
    for y in G.neighbours(x):
        all_nh += G.neighbours(y)

    # Remove from the list of neighbors the current node and its immediate neighbors
    all_nh = set(all_nh) - set([x]) - set(G.neighbours(x))

    # Create new edges (x -> z)
    edges = map(lambda z: (x, z), all_nh)

    # Add them to the new graph
    TC.add_edges_from(edges)
```

Note that the `set` in python is a container for *unique* values, thus, `set(a) - set(b)` will remove entries of `b` from `a`.

The for loop to extract all neighbors of neighbors could be reduced and (probably speedup) a bit more by using list comprehension:

```
all_nh = [z for y in G.neighbors(x) for z in G.neighbors(y)]
```

Yielding something like this:

```
def transitive_closure(G):
    TC = G.copy()
    for x in G:
        all_nh = [z for y in G.neighbors(x) for z in G.neighbors(y)]
        all_nh = set(all_nh) - set([x]) - set(G.neighbors(x))
        edges = map(lambda z: (x, z), all_nh)
        TC.add_edges_from(edges)
    return TC
```

Comment: I tried your code but it seems that TC = nx.copy(G) is not working      File "Graphs.py", line 89, in transitive_closure
    TC = nx.copy(G)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @user4252332 So, after I coded the whole function for you, you cannot even use 5 seconds of your time to solve that typo yourself? Is as easy as to google how to copy a graph with `networkx`. I'm not going to fix that one for you.

Comment: Ok sorry for bothering you more. I changed a code to fix copy issues. Can I ask you how to obtain instead of edge (no directional or bi directional an one directional edge)

Comment: @user4252332 Didn't understand that last question. As the code is right now, it should generate directional edges from `x to z`. What is your desired behaviour?

Comment: its ok sorry it was my mistake

Comment: Hmm your algorithen is working properly for flow of information between 3 nodes. What can i change to obtain the flow for infinity many nodes. so when i will have a node a, b,c,d and flow from a-b, b-c, c-d to obtain no tonly flows a-c and b-d but also a-d. Many thnaks for help

Comment: @user4252332 That is NP-hard, not easy to code, and completely out of this question. Is not easy to generalize to arbitrary number of neighbours.. You can try opening a new question.